# How do I get self signed SSL certificates to work locally on Mac OSX?

Tags: mac, .htaccess, ssl, https, httpd

I'm trying to test a local page on my local git repository. Unfortunately, the SSL certificates I installed using OpenSSL and Mod_SSL aren't seeming to work.

I've worked on checking the httpd file and watching the log. Though to be honest, my knowledge of web ends with HTML/CSS and .09 percent of JS and PHP. I'm beyond lost at this point. Isn't there a way to get the local server to run https using the keychain certificate wizard? Our other tech recommended the following:

> Execute a GET request (you can watch your headers in your browser with Firebug or write a quick PHP cURL script, or just telnet to port 443 and execute the request manually). This should tell you if authentication is failing due to the certificates or if the vhost is not configured correctly for the local site.

Though, again, out of my skillset. There's gotta be an easier way to do this.

OS is 10.5.8

Comment: "the SSL certificates I installed .. aren't seeming to work" - How about an error code, or any details on what the software has to say about the certificate? Details please.

Comment: @Chris. No errors, page just doesn't load. Just goes into the typical unable to connect when going to that localhost page.

Comment: What httpd are you using, Apache? Can you post the configuration file (specifically the area related to the SSL virtual host); feel free to scrub an personal data?

Comment: @Chris. Here are the links to the httpd, vhosts and httpd-ssl. I have SSL disabled right now, due to being unable to access anything at all on apache when it's enabled. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25067517/httpd-ssl.conf .... http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25067517/httpd-vhosts.conf .... http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25067517/httpd.conf

Comment: Can you add the output of http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cs-www to the question?